# swfupload not working with auth

Tags: php, flash, apache, authentication, swfupload

I am currently using swfupload to upload my files and it works wonderfully, but on our test sites we have a basic auth on apache, so google isn't able to spider the site before it goes live. What happens is the user logs into our site once and gets authenticated and then when they use swfupload and select their files and hits open it then asks for the username and password again and I'd really not want it to ask again. On Chrome it actually totally fails. The trickiest part is the swfupload doesn't go to one particular url either, so I can't just make an exception to that page only. Plz help.

Comment: I realize this probably isn't what you're looking for, but I'd recommend moving to something like plupload, uploadify, or jQuery-file-upload. I used to use swfupload but got really tired of its flash dependency and the headaches it created. I'm using plupload now and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we eventually ended up doing is making it so it only authenticates if post isn't passed in.

```
<Limit GET>
        Require valid-user
        Satisfy any
</Limit>
<Limit POST>
        Allow from all
</Limit>
```